# Extract specific values using Regex Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create an expression that extracts strings greater than 125 from a given string input.

```
var input = "YH300s, H900H, 234, 90.5, +12D, 48E, R180S, 190A, 350A, J380S";
```

Please view the link for further reference to my script/data example.

[DonotFiddle_Regex example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gp9WTM)

Here is my current expression attempt (*):

```
Regex.Matches(input,@"(?!.*\..*)[^\s\,]*([2-5][\d]{2,})[^\s\,]*"))
```

From the above expression, the only output is `350A, J380S`.

However I would like to extract the following output from the input string (see link above for further reference):

```
YH300s, H900H, R180S, 190A, 350A, J380S
```

Any further guide as to where I may be going wrong would be very much appreciated. Apology in advance if my context is not clear, as I am still novice in writing regex expressions.

Comment: I've added some of the essential information for the question into the question itself. While providing an example on another site is great, its also good to put enough information into the actual question so that it doesn't depend on an external site to be helpful

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Comment: Does it have to be solved 100% with regular expressions?

Comment: @Ryan, not necessarily.  I am open to other suggestion.  Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // an example of input
        var input = "YH300s, H900H, 234, 90.5, +12D, 48E, R180S, 190A, 350A, J380S";

        var parts = input.Split(new[]{", "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // regex for numbers (including negative and floating-point)
        var regex = new Regex(@"[-]?[\d]?[\.]?[\d]+");

        foreach(var part in parts)
        {
            // there can be many matches, e.g. "A100B1111" => "100" and "1111"            
            foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(part))
            {
                if (double.Parse(m.Value) > 125)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(part);
                    break;
                }
            }                   
        }           
    }
}
```

output

```
YH300s
H900H
234
R180S
190A
350A
J380S
```

Comment: Dangit that's what I was gonna say.

Comment: That's utterly genius.  Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: @user3070072, see update. i added `+` to regex, it is important in order to get full number

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I can use your answer as guide, if I need to add anythign further.  This great help and saves so much time.  Thanks a million for the update.

Comment: This solution has 1 major flaw: it will treat negative numbers as positive ones. My solution takes care of them. Try with `-1234F`, it will be output with this code.

Comment: @stribizhev, right. i added a fix. thanks for suggestion

Comment: Good, but I also see no point in writing `\d\d\d+`. It is the same as `\d+`.

Comment: Hi @ASh, Sorry to bother you again, the new REgex expressions outputting decimal values such as `98.345`, however I would like to extract only whole numbers >125.  I have added in rule but the regex code does not seem to recognizing it. Here is an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZyC2mg

Comment: @user3070072, i modified it: changed regex and also used double.parse instead of int.parse. short regex is easier to modify than a long one. i suggest update question to add this rule.

Comment: @ASh.  Thank you very much.  I very much appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Just FYI: `[\d]` is the same as `\d`.

Comment: @stribizhev, i'm getting lost  in \ and ? without brackets []

Comment: @Ash: You can just use `var regex = new Regex(@"-?\d?\.?\d+");`.

Comment: @stribizhev, thank you for tip. i don't work with regex often and format with [] is easier for me to read

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex (for numbers greater than `125`) if you dont want to process the matches:

```
(?!.*\..*)[^\s\,]*(12[5-9]|1[3-9]\d|[2-9]\d{2}|\d{4,})[^\s\,]*
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Code:

```
var input = "YH300s, H900H, 234, 90.5, +12D, 48E, R180S, 190A, 350A, J380S";

foreach(var match in Regex.Matches(input,@"(?!.*\..*)[^\s\,]*(12[5-9]|1[3-9]\d|[2-9]\d{2}|\d{4,})[^\s\,]*"))
    {

        Console.WriteLine(match);

    }
```

See [Demo on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CWDh8M)

Answer (score 2):

You can make it even shorter with **LINQ** and a regex that would take care of **double** values (with `-` and `+`), even on OSes with a comma set as decimal separator:

```
var input = "YH300s, H900H, 234, 90.5, +12D, 48E, R180S, 190A, 350A, J380S";
var reslts = input.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Where( p.Any(n => Char.IsDigit(n)) && 
                         p => double.Parse(Regex.Match(p, @"[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?").Value,
                 System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us")) > 125).ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

The `p.Any(n => Char.IsDigit(n))` part checks if we have any digits inside, then we match numbers with `[-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` regex, and parse them as double values for further comparison.

Answer (score 1):

In your regex you wrote your numbers should start with one digit between 2 and 5 but in your desired result there is H900H, R180S, 190A which dont begin with one of those - so there is a Problem with what you actually want as result.

If you want to match strings with starting digits between 2-5 maybe try:
`@"\w*[2-5]\d{2,}\w*"`